# How to fix inconsistent reading of <audio> tags for soundfx in Text-to-speech file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-text-to-speech

I have been using Google Text-to-Speech API to read aloud posts from Reddit. This has been successful thus far until I tried to add a 'click' sound effect to break up major posts. Because of the limit of characters allowed to be passed to the Google Cloud API I split the sections up into >= 5,000 characters. The problem is that the first file renders as audio easily with the click sound included between the  tags, but the second and third renderings do not include this sound effect. I stored the sound affect in Google Cloud Storage, set the bucket to public, and have proven that it works in the first render. Please find the text file below as well as the code used to create the render using the API. I am not getting any error codes.

I've tried limiting the size of the file, reformatting the text files in various ways, and searching here for an existing answer.

Code used to render the files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""Google Cloud Text-To-Speech API sample application .

Example usage:
    python quickstart.py
"""


def run_quickstart():
    # [START tts_quickstart]
    """Synthesizes speech from the input string of text or ssml.

    Note: ssml must be well-formed according to:
        https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/
    """
    from google.cloud import texttospeech
    from sys import argv
    script, filename, audioout = argv
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
    with open(filename,'r', encoding ='utf-8') as content:
        txt = content.read()

    # Set the text input to be synthesized
    synthesis_input = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(ssml=txt)

    # Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
    # voice gender ("neutral")
    voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code='en-US-Wavenet-D',
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.enums.SsmlVoiceGender.MALE)

    # Select the type of audio file you want returned
    audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

    # Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
    # voice parameters and audio file type
    response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)

    # The response's audio_content is binary.
    with open(audioout, 'wb') as out:
        # Write the response to the output file.
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print('                                                                  ')
        print('_________________________________')
        print('Audio content written to file: ', audioout)
        print('_________________________________')
        print('                                                                  ')
     # [END tts_quickstart]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_quickstart()
```

Succesfully rendered ssml file with soundfx

```
<speak>
<say-as interpret-as ="characters">r/</say-as>Ask Reddit
<emphasis level="moderate">What's a cool fact about the human body that a lot of people don't know?</emphasis>
<break time="5s"/>
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
Your liver can regenerate, and much faster than you think. I had a quarter of my liver removed, and a month later it was back.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
You have enough potasium in your body to create a very small bomb
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
Some people are born with extra ribs called cervical ribs which grow from the C7 vertebrae in the neck. It's a weird and rare mutation that a lot of people don't even know they have, although it is also a cause of thoracic outlet syndrome, which is where pressure is applied to the nerves, veins and arteries running into the arms. It can be really painful, and in some rare cases can cause gangrene in the arms. If left untreated it can kill you if you're really unlucky. (source: I have the non-cervical rib induced variety)  
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
Some people will cough if they put something in one ear, a very small percentage will cough if something is in either ear. It is called Arnold’s ear-cough reflex.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
A woman was found without a cerebelum, the part of the brain that controls motor abilities of the body. She is alive, and has no real side effects from this condition that we know of.

Okay to clarify, her cerebellum was not removed nor did I do it. She was born without one, and the medical professionals (Again, not me) found out after she complained about a headache which lead to an MRI.

It is worth noting that the cerebellum doesn’t control voluntary movement; that is the motor cortex. The cerebellum’s main role is basically to try to match intention (from the motor cortex) to the action that is actually being performed by the muscles. Still interesting, though!

You know the smell of rain, or disturbed soil? It's a compound produced by bacteria called Geosmin, and the human nose is extremely sensitive to it. We can smell it at as low a concentration as 5 parts per trillion.

We can smell rain better then sharks can smell blood. I actually just learned about this. There Is a podcast from Stuff You Should Know that goes over all this info. The smell of rain.

That episode of SYSK short is cool. Also, they said that it could be that we have evolved to smell Geosmin to enhance our ability to find water.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
Natural redheads require increased doses of anesthesia, due to some connection with the mutated melanocortin one receptor. I’m a natural redhead myself, and developed a fear of dentists because I’d always feel what they were doing!

Eventually I had an issue that couldn’t be ignored, and had to find a new dentist. At my first visit he took one look at me, and said “You’re a real redhead, huh?” “Yup.” “(Hygienist), get me 4x the novocaine!” I knew I’d found my man, and he’s been treating me ever since... also shed my fears, since dental work is much less unpleasant when you’re actually numb before they start.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
Archaeologist here. You can give birth after you've died. Occasionally we will come across a really confronting burial where the skeleton of an unborn child is halfway through its mothers pelvis. Generally what happens is the woman has died before giving birth and after burial a build up of gases from decomposition forces the baby out. We refer to this as "coffin birth".
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
Really late but I discovered this thing during my thesis.

We were researching patients with neurological problems and people who had brain injuries and we found a woman in her 30 that had had part of her brain removed. More specifically the area that activates when you move your body.

Well she was moving and talking with just some minor missteps and theoretically it was not possible, she was paralyzed in the first 3 months after the operation (she was caught in a car accident if I remember correctly).

We were trying out a new scanner for the brain and we found out that an area of the brain that wasn't supposed to work and control the movement was doing just that. The occipital area (usually controls the vision) was now working as a motor control area.

The brain is really amazing...
</speak>
```

ssml file not rendering succesfully

```
<speak>
There is a muscle, called palmaris longus, in the forearm missing in about 10% of the population. You can easily test if you have it by putting your pinky and thumb together, while holding your palm facing up, and flex the hand upwards. If 1 tendon is standing out more than the others that's palmaris longus.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
you mostly breathe out of one nostril at a time, and the ‘dominant nostril switches every hour or so.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
When were in an unfamiliar environment we sleep with half our brain at a time kinda like sharks and that's why we wake up easier.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
The optimal human circadian rhythm is actually closer to 25 hours than 24 [in experiments depriving people of sunlight & other triggers that maintain your circadian rhythm].   

Just a couple hundred million years ‘til the planet slows down to match our sleep cycle!
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
Your hands and feet alone account for more than half of all the bones in your body (106/206)
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
Cutting the corpus callosum ( connects two brain hemispheres) can produce some freaky results. Such as your hand doing shit that your conscious mind is t aware of, writing a sentence or scratching an itch without knowing for instance.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
I saw a program back in the dark ages when I was a kid. It was all about the brain. One of the things they talked about was that procedure. They had a guy they were testing. One hand did better with creative things, the other did better with logic. At one point they were trying to get him to do something with the hand that didn't have an easier time with it (I think it was something like stacking blocks). He wasn't supposed to use the hand that could do it better, but as if the hand had a mind of its own it kept interjection itself and at one point literally grabbed the hand having a problem and moved it out of the way in obvious frustration.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
I remember watching a video about this sort of experiment way back when I took intro psych as an elective. With one guy, they asked what he wanted to be when he grew up, and gave each hand a pen. One side wanted to be a doctor (or something similar, it's been years so I don't remember) while the other wanted to be a racecar driver. Some people were put in front of a screen with a divider in front of their face, so each eye was blind to whatever was going on on the other side of the body. Then they did exercises with a pen in each hand. And then for example if the screen said to draw a toadstool, one half might draw an actual toadstool and the other might draw a toad and a stool. They found some really interesting quirks. Makes me wonder if those people might have "conversations" between the halves of their brain, communicating through writing or something since they aren't physically linked to transmit info anymore.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
As far as I know, they still sever the corpus callosum in some cases of of severe epilepsy, to help prevent a seizure from doing damage across both hemispheres.
    <audio src="https://storage.googleapis.com/sounds_text_to_speech/click.ogg">
    </audio>
My son has hypoplasia of the corpus callosum and even since he was a baby (he’s 11 now) when he tries to grasp something or use his hands for anything he will immobilize one arm to use the other. In therapy we worked on getting him to use both hands together but while one hand might be reaching for a toy, the other hand would knock the toy off his table or throw it. He would get so frustrated and start yelling (he is nonverbal) & flailing both arms around. We have to be careful to keep an eye on him because another thing that goes with this defect is he has a high tolerance for pain. So he might wedge one arm between his wheelchair armrest so hard that it’s cutting off the circulation but not show any signs of discomfort. He has a medical bed with tall wooden slats around it and he will stick one arm through a slot and get it stuck on purpose. Sometimes I think he would prefer to amputate arm & is actively attempting to kill the mischievous arm. Brains are weird.
</speak>
```

As of now my plan is to add the sound effect in production along with the music and general editing, however this has proven to be tedious and rendering it with the audio initially would be preferable. I've looked at at the documentation and SSML guidelines and have failed to come up with a solution independently.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the same issue as you had, and I noticed that in your SSML file that you mentioned that is not rendering successfully, is due to there is the symbol '&' written 3 times.
When I deleted the character '&', it works properly.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#tips_for_using_ssml), you shoud avoid XML control characters like <', '>', '&', quotes, and quotation marks in the text to be converted to audio.
So, based on this information, I would recommend you to replace these characters to text.

Keep also in mind that [Cloud Text-to-Speech Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries) is in pre-release state, and might change.